# Issue with Dynamic Page Loading and JS for Subpages

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic-content

I'm facing an issue with dynamically loading subpages along with JS dedicated to these subpages.

I have a main template:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="menu>
<a href="/user_form">User form</a>
</div>
<div id="main-content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

where I load content using a JS function:

```
function loadPage(page) {
  const pageLoadingSpinner = new LoadingSpinner('loading-spinner');
  pageLoadingSpinner.show();

  const loadContentPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(page, {
          headers: {
              'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
          }
      })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(html => {
          resolve(html);
      })
      .catch(error => {
          reject(error);
      });
  });

  loadContentPromise
      .then(html => {
          setTimeout(() => {
              document.getElementById('main-content').innerHTML = html;
              pageLoadingSpinner.hide();
          }, 200);
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
          pageLoadingSpinner.hide();
      });
}
```

Here's an example code for a subpage:

```
<form id="myForm">
...
</form>
<script src="/static/script.js"></script>
```

And content of script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    submitForm(event);
  });
});
function submitForm(event) {
//ajax
}
```

However, the code in script.js doesn't execute correctly. Unfortunately, event.preventDefault() is not working, and the form is still getting submitted in classic method.

Any insights into why the event.preventDefault() is not functioning as expected would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to solve the problem with chatGPT, but it keeps suggesting fancier and fancier random solutions. As far as I can see, the problem is that it dynamically loads the content, which is then not recognised in script.js

Thank you!

Comment: Have all scripts in the calling page and delegate from a static container.

Comment: I would like to avoid this, I am looking for a way to keep the JS in a separate file for greater clarity.

Unfortunately I didn't understand the bit with the "static container" part.

Comment: The problem is not that `event.preventDefault()` somehow "fails", but that your JS does not get executed at all. But even if you fixed that in a way as explained in the duplicate, you can probably still not expect `$(document).ready()` to fire again - the document you are inserting this in, _has_ already been "ready" long ago.

Comment: What you CAN do is the following: `const main = document.getElementById('main-content'); main.innerHTML = html; const src = main.querySelector('script').getAttribute('src'); const script = document.createElement('script'); document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script); script.src=src;`

Comment: Sweet! At the moment, my code looks like this, it handles subpage changes, adds <script> to the section in the head, I have also added a check to see if the js file has already been loaded.

I am working on adding code to remove the <script> after leaving a subpage.

https://pastebin.com/gLMPYh2e

Comment: You do not need to remove it. If the function name is the same, it will be overwritten

Comment: I mean: I want to use specific js files on specific subpages. Although since it has already been loaded, removing it will not change anything...